# How can i simplify show/hide div when using onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i currently have a bunch of divs and a dropdown using onchange event when selecting it displays the div and hide them onchange as well. currently i am showing one div at a time and everything works well but i have too many codes. is there anyway i can simplify my code?

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function changeDiv(val)
    {
        var id = val;
        if (id == '1')
        {
            $('#div_1').css('display','table-row');
            $('#div_2').css('display','none');
            $('#div_3').css('display','none');
            $('#div_4').css('display','none');
        }
        if (id == '2')
        {
            $('#div_2').css('display','table-row');
            $('#div_1').css('display','none');
            $('#div_3').css('display','none');
            $('#div_4').css('display','none');
        }
        if (id == '3')
        {
            $('#div_3').css('display','table-row');
            $('#div_1').css('display','none');
            $('#div_2').css('display','none');
            $('#div_4').css('display','none');
        }
        if (id == '4')
        {
            $('#div_4').css('display','table-row');
            $('#div_1').css('display','none');
            $('#div_2').css('display','none');
            $('#div_3').css('display','none');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Select menu

```
<select class="seletmenu" onChange="changDiv(this.value)">
    <option value="1">Select 1</option>
    <option value="2">Select 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select 3</option>
    <option value="4">Select 4</option>
</select>
```

Divs

```
<div id="div_1">
    <div>Testing select 1</div>
</div>

<div id="div_2">
    <div>Testing select 2</div>
</div>

<div id="div_3">
    <div>Testing select 3</div>
</div>

<div id="div_4">
    <div>Testing select 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can reduce it to this:

```
$('.selectmenu').change(function () {
    $('.foo').hide();
    $('#div_' + this.value).css('display', 'table-row');
})
```

just by adding a common class (e.g. "foo") to your divs.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/39sohvmn/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class instead of all Ids .

Markup:

```
<div id="div_1" class="toggleDiv">
<div>Testing select 1</div></div>

<div id="div_2" class="toggleDiv">
<div>Testing select 2</div></div>

<div id="div_3" class="toggleDiv">
<div>Testing select 3</div></div>

<div id="div_4" class="toggleDiv">
<div>Testing select 4</div></div>
```

Then you can hide all divs and show the one you want like so...

```
function changeDiv(val)
{
    $('.toggleDiv').css('display','none');
    $('#div_'+val).css('display','table-row');
}
```

Viola, same functionality accomplished, much less code.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, you may refactor your code as follow:

```
function changeDiv(val) {    
    $('#div_1').css('display','none');
    $('#div_2').css('display','none');
    $('#div_3').css('display','none');
    $('#div_4').css('display','none');
    $('#div_' + val).css('display','table-row');
}
```